# how to fetch ParseUser object by objectId?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have `objectId`  and I want to fetch `ParseUser` object which has same `objectId`.
I have read that we can use `get` to get `ParseUser` by `id` at [Parse](https://parse.com/) documentation but syntax is not given there. If anyone know please help me.

I have tried this but it is not working.

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
query.whereEqualTo("objectId", userId);
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseUser> object, ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e==null)
        for(ParseUser obj: object)
        {
            adress.setText(obj.getString("address"));
            contact.setText(obj.getString("contact"));
        }
        else
        {
            adress.setText("Not found");
        }

    }
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following code to get the user;

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("_User");
    query.whereEqualTo("objectId",userId);
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                //List contain object with specific user id.

            } else {
                // error
            }
        }
    });
```

Hope this helps
Regards.

Comment: thank you for your answer but if i am using a variable(here userId ) instead of a value like "ABC" it is not working. plz help

Comment: Dear Parya; I update the answer in a way that remove the misunderstanding. Please try and inform me. Instead of string value "ABC", you can give the userId directly. Hope this helps. Regards.

Comment: ya  i have tried in the same way but it is giving error 101. but if i am giving direct string then it is working. thanks for your response.